# How use ubuntu-sdk with another distribution

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I'm bored with ubuntu fixed software version, so I would like to switch manjaro (because of rolling release).

But I want develop application for ubuntu touch (ubuntu-sdk). Have you an idea how use this sdk under another distribution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to install a VM running ubuntu under the alternative version of linux.  I use this every day at work, where I have ubuntu and centos VMs running on VMWare Workstation under windows (and I have both setup with Samba, so I can copy files between VMs).  In my past job I had Windows and Centos VMs running under an Ubuntu desktop.

I've had some experience of installing RPM packages under ubuntu using Alien, but it tends to be a game of basically unpacking the package to get the application tree, and putting it in /opt and then working through the scripts/config files to resolve dependencies to some other package or refer to something that is in a different path.

I suspect developing in an ubuntu VM will be much easier for you, especially as with X running on your desktop, you can forward X connections to your ubuntu VM and have the GUI display on your desktop, and if you setup your desktop to export /home via NFS, you could configure your VM to share your home folder within that NFS mount, so you can have your workspace on your native computer and just use the VM for emulation and compilation.

Comment: I used to develop maemo apps, and they had the same problem, developing under windows.  I thought this might give you some hints: http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=34517

Comment: debootstrap might be worth a mention here, too.   You can use it on other distributions to create a directory containing whatever flavor of ubuntu you want and install the SDK under that.

Comment: A VM is not a solution to the problem. It should be possible to run the sdk naitive and I don't see how debootstrap should fix those problems without beeing an ugly hacky workaround, too.

Comment: If the problem you're trying to solve is 'developing for ubuntu torch, whilst running a non ubuntu desktop' then yes it is a solution to the problem.

Comment: As an aside, I've had some success with VirtualBox as a Vm too, albeit without the functionality of vmware workstation (but it is free).